# Android: (Newb Question) Programatically creating views based on xml

Tags: android

Sorry for the Newb-ness.

I want to create a list of view elements in a `LinearLayout` (vertical).  I created an xml layout that is a `TableLayout` called "category_list.xml"

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
   <ImageView />
   <TextView />
   <CheckBox />
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I want to iterate an array, on each iteration create a new TableLayout view and add it to the LinearLayout.  The peice I'm missing is creating a new TableLayout based on the above xml.

Something like

```
TableLayout t = new TableLayout( R.layout.category_list );
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Is it better to generate the TableLayout programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or by using the static View.inflate function

```
TableLAyout t = (TableLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.category_list, null);
```

Anyway, be carefull with inflating and deleting too many views in your app, as short lived objects leak memory. Consider using an ListView with and Adapter instead.

Comment: I wanted to use a ListView originally, but I am under the impression that to use a ListView, the activity is required to extend ListActivity, which I can't because it is already extending MapActivity.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a [`LayoutInflater`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to "inflate" the xml files.  You can get `LayoutInflater` in an activity by using [`getLayoutInflater()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLayoutInflater()).  Here's how it works (assuming the id of your `LinearLayout` is "parent"):

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
TableLayout t = (TableLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_list, parent);
```